# Can't download Ubuntu Server 17 from my country

Tags: downloads, cdn

I'm trying to download Ubuntu Server 17 but the link doesn't work for me.

I'm in Iran and this link that generates for me 
doesn't work correctly 
http://mirror.rasanegar.com/ubuntu/cd/17.10/ubuntu-17.10-server-amd64.iso

None of the other mirrors seem to work either.

Comment: Who knows. Perhaps the mirror is down temporarily, or taken of line permanently. Perhaps there is a power outage or reboot problem. Does it really matter? Just download from another one

Comment: i was trying to download from another mirror. but any other link doesn't generate for me.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 17.10 has problems with damaging the BIOS of certain laptops, so it's no longer available and, instead, [17.10.1 was released recently](https://fossbytes.com/ubuntu-17-10-1-download-iso-torrent-bios-fix/) to replace it.

To get the newer version, try [downloading the ISO on the main download site](http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.10/ubuntu-17.10.1-server-amd64.iso) or, from the server you were trying to get it from, http://mirror.rasanegar.com/ubuntu/cd/17.10/ubuntu-17.10.1-server-amd64.img (note that `ubuntu-17.10` is changed to `ubuntu-17.10.1`).